# Geth implementation with node JS on elasticbeanstalk enviornment

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, node-modules, geth

Hi I am working on node with geth it was running fine on my local machine but when i deploy it on elastic beanstalk server when I execute the geth.start code with require gethoptions i get EACCES error.

Comment: Check your port, it might be used by some other process.

Comment: It's not working